# Python :- Read a text file and convert it to upper case and write to a second file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-writing

Read a text file and convert it to upper case and write to a second file.

```
fo = open('/home/venkat/Desktop/Data Structure/Python/test.txt', 'r')
for x in fo.read():
    y = x.upper()
    fo1 = open('/home/venkat/Desktop/Data Structure/Python/write.txt', 'a')
    fo1.write(y)
```

Contents of test.txt :- **My name is Venkatesh**

Correct Output :-
MY NAME IS VENKATESH

I am getting :-
**H**MY NAME IS VENKATES

*H is not coming at the last place, rather it is moving the first character to second. Why?*

Comment: I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, you are not closing your files any more. The data is only written by sure, when the files are closed. Since you opened a new file for each character, and don't explicitly close the files, the order of characters written is not deterministic.

Open files with the `with` statement ensures, that files are correctly closed:

```
with open('/home/venkat/Desktop/Data Structure/Python/test.txt', 'r') as inp:
    y = inp.read().upper()
with open('/home/venkat/Desktop/Data Structure/Python/write.txt', 'a') as out:
    out.write(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add newline char `\n` at start of line.

**Ex:**

```
with open(filename) as infile, open(filename1, "a") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write("\n" + line.upper())
```